# What film has a boy living with a killer instead of his father?

Tags: identify-this-movie

Trying to remember a film that I watched around 2003 about this boy who lived with his step-father and crept in his cart and watched him kill and cremate the body? Anyone know what it is called? I alse remember something about a baseball bat!

The police do not believe him, but his father tells the killer that his son never lies to him. The killer stabs his victim in the car while his step-son hiding in the car sees. He then burns him in a small crematoriom.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like [Domestic Disturbance](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0249478/) Vince Vaughn is the step-father and the boy hides in his car one night and sees him kill. The boys actual father John Travolta is the only one that believes him.  Try to add more details if you post another question it helps a lot.